# How is Symfony FOSUserBundle stores the salt

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a project, which consists of 2 parts, web part and java part, in the web one, i'm using symfony with the `FOSUserBundle` to manage users, the 2 applications shares the same database. `FOSUserBundle` uses a slated SHA1 to crypt the password, i would like to be authenticate with the java app, but i couldn't figure out how the salting mecanisme works in symfony.
In the `[Model/User.php][1]` class, in the constructor, there is line:

```
$this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
```

As we can see here, the salt is generated using a random number `mt_rand()`,
I have 2 questions here, if the salt is "random", then in the login process, how a new salt is generated to compare it with the in the database? 
and is the salt stored somewhere?

Comment: It's stored in the database together with the hashed value.

Comment: If it is not stored in a seperate column, how is it retrieved?

Comment: Have you tried to check the database? And code maybe?

Comment: yes, in the database there is a "salt" column, but when i try to generate a hash with that salt (and the password) i dont get the same hash result.

Comment: Well, you presumably are generating it differently then. The same salt + the password are guaranteed to produce the same hash

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the database where you're storing all the fields is correctly referencing the FOSUserBundle.  It sounds like because you haven't properly defined your parent and child constructors that it is simply a blank salt that is being applied to the passwords that you're giving it, hence why the different hashed strings when the salt is applied.

A quick example:

Retrieve the salt from the user:

```
 $encoder_service = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
 $encoder = $encoder_service->getEncoder($user);
```

Retrieve current hashed password from user and salt the new password

```
$currentpass = $user->getPassword();
$newpass = $encoder->encodePassword($newPassword, $user->getSalt());
```

Then you can compare to two hashes to ensure that the password being parsed is the same as the password stored

```
 if (strcmp($currentpass, $newpass) == 0) {
      // if two passwords are the same, do something here
 } else {
      throw $this->createNotFoundException('Error here');
 }
```

Comment: `strcmp($currentpass, $newpass)` --- one should use `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\StringUtils::equals()` to compare hashes in constant time.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, that didn't cross my mind as I knocked up a quick example for the OP, so I just used string compare